# On-Behalf_Of Flow - Office AddIn SSO

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, single-sign-on, office-js, office-addins

I have successfully got the SSO to work in my Office Addin using this code (just testing at the moment)

```
try {
    let userTokenEncoded = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({
      allowSignInPrompt: true,
    });
```

So my Azure AD Application is working asit should. I get my JWT token down and if I decrypt it, it looks ok.

I now want to use this token to connect to dataverse but when I try and use it , I get  401 error (makes sense as the token is not for dataverse eventhough I have added this permission into the application registration.

[image]

I have been reading that I may need to implement an on-behalf flow so this token can be used to access dataverse and its not as simple as just adding the permission in the Office SSO Application registration.

Comment: The OBO flow is described in depth in the [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a middle-tier service to your solution that can exchange the access token you are getting from the call to the getAccessToken method in the add-in with an access token that can be used in the request to Dataverse.

Comment: ok, how do you recommend for me to create a middle-tier service ? Something like node express, would that be ok ?

Comment: The documentation describes how to create a middle tier with node.js and ASP.NET.

node.js: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs
ASP.NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-aspnet

Comment: You can also choose not to use SSO and then get an access token to Dataverse directly using the Implicit flow, and you won't need a middle tier.

Comment: so if don't use SSO ? Then will the user have to log on all the time ? When they open the add-in - I will be eventually using Outlook Add-in.

Comment: If you choose to store the access token and also a refresh token then the user won't have to log on every time the add-in opens.